# PHP regex replace with diffrent action for each result

Tags: php, html, regex, iframe, preg-replace

In **PHP** I'm trying to replace all **iframe** tags with paragraph tag that include the **ifame** tag.

in other words im trying to surround the **iframe** tag with `<p>` tag that have a random number.

everything is working fine except when ***$record*** contains more than one **iframe** tag, in that case it would give the same paragraph number for the all the `<p>` tags.

here is my code:

```
$x = rand(1, 99);
$replacement = '<p' . $x . '>$1</p' . $x . '><br>';
$record = preg_replace("/(<iframe.*<\/iframe>)/U", $replacement, $record);
```

i want to give a unique number for for the

tag for each **iframe** tag
ex:

```
<p1><iframe>sometext</iframe></p1>
<p2><iframe>sometext</iframe></p2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = <<<'HTML'
<p1><iframe>sometext1</iframe></p1>
<p2><iframe>sometext2</iframe></p2>
HTML;

$re = "/(<iframe[^>]*>.*?<\/iframe>)/U";

echo preg_replace_callback($re, function ($a) {
    $x = rand(1, 99);
    return '<p' . $x . '>'.$a[1].'</p' . $x . '><br>';
}, $s);
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, Perfect!